# asp.net return recordset as associated array

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-retrieval

I'm trying to dig into asp.net and C# and have some problems;

I've built a class to access db-data (don't ask why, it's an assignment).

```
public static class dbConn {

  public static ArrayList dbGet(string odbcStr, string sql) {
    OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection(odbcStr);
    ...
    ArrayList rowList = new ArrayList();
    ...
    while (DbReader.Read())
    {
        object[] values = new object[DbReader.FieldCount];
        DbReader.GetValues(values);
        rowList.Add(values);
    }
    ....
    return rowList;
```

I guess it's ok, my problem is how to show returned data;
in about.aspx.cs:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList RS = new ArrayList();
    RS = dbConn.dbGet("DSN=mysqloverodbc", "select * from pages");
    Array RSrow = RS[0];
    sqlText.Text = RS[0]; 
    //what I want here is to request [0]["PageID"] or similar.
```

Blinded by the complexity of .net, I've failed to get help at google.

regards,
//t

Comment: Are you supposed to display on a web page?  A win form?  Output to text file?  What are you being asked to do with the data?

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try `[0]["PageID"]`?

Comment: The assignment is actually a bit blurry, but to answer your q, I want to output the RS to a table at a web-page.

Comment: @abe, both sqlText.Text = RS[0] and = RS[0]["PageID"] give warning about "cannot implictly convert object to system.Array"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost there. Here is what you have to change.

```
Array RSrow = RS[0] as Array;
int pageIDIndex = 0; // Note :you have to know the column index in the table.i.e If the table has three columns, then the column index starts from 0 to columns length-1
sqlText.Text = RSrow.GetValue(pageIndexID).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `[0]["PageID"]`?

Your assignment to `sqlText.Text` will not work since `RS[0]` is an array.

Try this if sqlText is a TextBox:

```
sqlText.Text = RS[0]["PageID"].ToString();
```

Comment: hmm... Warning change to "cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'."

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't support associative arrays natively.

The problem with `sqlText.Text = RS[0]["PageID"].ToString();` is that the RS[0] gets to the first record of the ArrayList, which is an array of type Object -  `object[]`.  But `object[]` doesn't have an indexer that takes a string -- you can't specify a string value for the `object[]` array's index.

If you are stuck with using an object array, you will have to use index values for the item values. For example,

```
sqlText.Text = RS[0][0].ToString();   // Row 0, Column 0
```

The first `0` refers to the row, as it is an index into the `ArrayList`.
The second `0` refers to the column, as it is an index into an `object[]` you created on the line after your `while (DbReader.Read())` line.

The second index will be the columns in the order returned by the `DbReader`.